# Counting Faces, Edges, and Vertices of cubed 1-toroid

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

Trouble determining the Euler's characteristic on the shape below.
Here's what I counted: $G=(V,E,F) = (16,24,10)$
Shouldn't $χ$ be $0$?
[1-toroid.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAJ7L.png)

Comment: Isn't $G$ a triplet? Also the Euler characteristic seems to me to be $\chi=V-E+F=2$.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how you counted the values of $V$, $E$ and $F$; otherwise, all I can say is "count again".

Comment: sorry, it was quite sloppy and without context of how I counted. But that's irrelevant now.

Comment: Euler formula does not apply when the faces have holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have counted $(V,E,F)$ wrong.

This shape has a vertex for every single integer coordinate of a 2x4x4 grid in 3-D, so $V=32$.
It has 24 edges on the top layer, and another 24 on the bottom layer, with 16 edges from top to bottom, so $E=64$.
It has 8 faces on the top, 8 on the bottom, 4 on the inside hole, 12 around the outside, so $F=32$.

As you correctly predicted, $V-E+F = 32-64+32 = 0$.

Comment: thank you very much.